# CATransition Undeclared?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-animation

I'm trying to initialize a CATransition instance, but xCode keeps telling me that I'm making an *Use of undeclared identifier "CATransition". Did you mean "kCATransition"?*

The line in question is quite simple:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
```

What am I doing wrong? I've found this code several times over the web, but I can't figure out what am I doing different.

**EDIT:** Ok, so I have imported Quartz like suggested

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

But now I get a different message in the next line of code: "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString *const' to parameter of type 'NSCellType'"

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
[transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: You may need to do a clean build to pick up this change. It didn't work for me until I did a clean.

Answer (score 2):

you definitely need to #import

and here is my example of CATransition :

```
 - (IBAction)FavButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {

 FavoritesViewController *favVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FavoritesViewController"];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favVC];



CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:NO completion:nil];


 }
```

what this does:
     transition occurs when I press the favorite button

1. instantiate the controller I want to transition to : FavoritesViewController (make sure the name defined on the storyboard)

   1. allocate and init the navigation so the nav can be included in the transition
   2. start the animation, determine type: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html
   3. subtype : You want it going from bottom up, top -down, right-left...
      6.I want to present nav and I want to say animation: NO which means I do not want it to use default behavior